Resolving Lifetime Issues When Passing AsRef<Path> Parameter to Function Pointer in Rust
I'm working on my first Rust application and have encountered a problem related to borrowing values. My application involves parsing different kinds of text files using several functions that return Result<DataFrame, ParseError>. DataFrame is from the Polars library, and ParseError is my custom error type.
I have multiple file parsing functions with the following signature:
fn parse_file<P: AsRef<Path>>(file_path: P) -> Result<DataFrame, ParseError>

This allows me to pass either a string slice or a reference to std::path::Path.
Sometimes, I call these file parsing functions individually. Other times, I want to parse all files in a directory, so I need a single function that can parse an entire directory. For this, I intend to pass the file parsing function as a parameter.
Here is my current implementation:
type ParseFunction<P> = fn(P) -> Result<DataFrame, ParseError>;
fn parse_folder<P: AsRef<Path>>(
    dir: P,
    parse_function: ParseFunction<&Path>,
) -> Result<HashMap<String, DataFrame>, ParseError> {
    let mut map: HashMap<String, DataFrame> = HashMap::new();
    for entry in fs::read_dir(dir).map_err(|_| ParseError::ReadFolderError)? {
        let file = entry.map_err(|_| ParseError::ReadFolderError)?;
        let filename = file.file_name().to_string_lossy().into_owned();
        let path = file.path().clone();
        if filename.ends_with(".art") {
            map.insert(
                filename,
                parse_function(&path)?,
            ); 
        } //parse_function should be done with path here
    } //path is dropped here. Why is that not ok? 
    Ok(map)
}

This produces the error: error[E0597]: path does not live long enough
Why does Rust give me the error "path does not live long enough" in this context, and what is the correct way to write the parse_folder function to handle this borrowing issue?
I mainly want to understand the borrowing issue. I have tried a bunch of different things. The LLM's keep confidently suggesting things that do not work.
Here is an example of how i want to use the parse_folder function:
pub fn parse_art_file<P: AsRef<Path>>(
    file_path: P,
) -> Result<DataFrame, ParseError> {
    match read_and_decode_lines(&file_path) {
        // Attempt to read article parameters from the decoded lines
        Ok(lines) => read_article_parameters(lines),
        // Return an error if the file could not be read and decoded
        Err(_) => Err(ParseError::InvalidFile(file_path.as_ref().to_string_lossy().into_owned())),
    }
}

pub fn parse_art_folder<P: AsRef<Path>> (dir: P) -> Result<HashMap<String, DataFrame>, ParseError> {
    parse_folder(dir, parse_art_file)
}


ParseFunction<&Path> is the type of a function which takes references of some specific (unnamed) lifetime, that lifetime, being declared in parse_folder, necessarily lives past the scope the parse_folder (this fact is true of any lifetime parameters of a function). But the lifetime of &path is definitely smaller than that, because path is a local variable declared somewhere inside parse_folder, so is alive for at most the scope of parse_folder (in fact, for less than that scope). You should replace ParseFunction with a trait which has a function taking references of any lifetime

In parse_folder, the type of path is PathBuf (which has an impl AsRef<Path>). Instead of passing &path to parse_function, you can just pass path directly:
fn parse_folder<P: AsRef<Path>>(
    dir: P,
    parse_function: fn(file_path: PathBuf) -> Result<DataFrame, ParseError>,
) -> Result<HashMap<String, DataFrame>, ParseError> {
    let mut map: HashMap<String, DataFrame> = HashMap::new();
    for entry in fs::read_dir(dir).map_err(|_| ParseError::ReadFolderError)? {
        let file = entry.map_err(|_| ParseError::ReadFolderError)?;
        let filename_os = file.file_name();
        let filename = filename_os.to_string_lossy();
        if filename.ends_with(".art") {
            map.insert(filename.into(), parse_function(file.path())?);
        }
    }
    Ok(map)
}

I also moved the place where to_owned is called into the if statement (as into), so you don't make any unnecessary string copies.

Could you explain what you changed and why it was necessary?

@prog-fh, you are quite right. Is this better?
